# How do you initialize variables inside function scope and avoid global scope?

Tags: javascript

I have in the global space a variable set as follows:

```
let hoverMessageLock = 0;
```

This allows the function below to operate how I want. Its function is to add a message upon button hover and then delete said message and replace it with a new message upon another hover.

The issue I'm having is I would like to NOT use the global space for variables and instead put it inside the function itself. However the function itself is getting called over and over again per each hover event, so if I set hoverMessageLock = 0 in the function scope, it just keeps getting set to 0 over and over again. Therefor my switch statement doesn't work as intended as when its in the global scope.

I know in other programming languages that utilizes classes, you can set variables in the class scope and then alter them in the same way you would global scope inside your functions. Is there a way to do this as well here in Javascript?

```
let macroManager = {
    hoverMessage: function(message, style = "hovertext noTextSelect"){
        switch (hoverMessageLock){
            case 0:
                uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage(""+message+"", 0, 0, style);
                hoverMessageLock = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                uiManager.messageDirector.removeMessage();
                uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage(""+message+"", 0, 0, style);
                break;
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: why can't it be in global scope? And if you are wondering about classes, js does have those.

Comment: I just don't want to pollute the global space and trying to make a habit of it.

Comment: Ok, would something like class macroManger{...} work?

Comment: Yes it would work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an object, and that works nicely, just as you describe in class-based languages. Classes are simply a way of creating objects, and objects are all you need here.

Just add the property to your object:

```
let macroManager = {
    hoverMessageLock: 0,
    hoverMessage: function(message, style = "hovertext noTextSelect"){
        switch (this.hoverMessageLock){
            case 0:
                uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage(""+message+"", 0, 0, style);
                this.hoverMessageLock = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                uiManager.messageDirector.removeMessage();
                uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage(""+message+"", 0, 0, style);
                break;
        }
    },
}
```

Note that, depending on how you use the `hoverMessageLock` method, it's possible its `this` context could be lost (eg if you use it as an event handler) - this is easily fixed by defining it as an arrow function instead: `hoverMessage: (message, style = "hovertext noTextSelect") => { ... }`.

I would also recommend, if 0 and 1 are the only intended values of the `hoverMessageLock` variable/property, using boolean false/true values instead.

Comment: This solution fits best. The rest of the solutions here seem to work as well, but I hate how it makes my code look unreadable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *Immediately Executed Function Expression* (IIFE) for this.

```js
let macroManager = (function(hoverMessageLock) {
  return {
    hoverMessage: function(message, style = "hovertext noTextSelect") {
      switch (hoverMessageLock) {
        case 0:
          uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage("" + message + "", 0, 0, style);
          hoverMessageLock = 1;
          break;
        case 1:
          uiManager.messageDirector.removeMessage();
          uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage("" + message + "", 0, 0, style);
          break;
      }
    },
  };
})(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class macroManger{
  constructor(){
     this.hoverMessageLock = 0;
  }
  hoverMessage(message, style = "hovertext noTextSelect"){
    switch (this.hoverMessageLock) {
        case 0:
          uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage("" + message + "", 0, 0, style);
          this.hoverMessageLock = 1;
          break;
        case 1:
          uiManager.messageDirector.removeMessage();
          uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage("" + message + "", 0, 0, style);
          break;
      }
  }
}

macroManger1 = new macroManger();
macroManger1.hoverMessage(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a local scope using the IIFE expression:

```js
var macroManager = getMacroManager();

function getMacroManager() {
    return (function () {
        var hoverMessageLock = 0;

        return {
            hoverMessage: function (message, style = "hovertext noTextSelect") {
                switch (hoverMessageLock) {
                    case 0:
                        uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage("" + message + "", 0, 0, style);
                        hoverMessageLock = 1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        uiManager.messageDirector.removeMessage();
                        uiManager.messageDirector.addMessage("" + message + "", 0, 0, style);
                        break;
                }
            },
        };
    })();
}
```

So each time you call `getMacroManager()` you will get a separate instance, thus, `hoverMessageLock` will work as a local variable, which is what you expect to happen.

Here's more info about IIFE:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE.